# AEM server is running locally but localhost refuses to connect

Tags: java, aem

I am trying to run an AEM site locally on a mac I run the server using the command

`java -Xmx2048m -jar AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar`

I am getting this response back:

```
Loading quickstart properties: default
Loading quickstart properties: instance
Low-memory action set to fork
Using 64bit VM settings, min.heap=1024MB, min permgen=256MB, default fork arguments=[-Xmx1024m, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m]
The JVM reports a heap size of 2048 MB, meets our expectation of 1024 MB +/- 20
Setting properties from filename '/Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar'
Verbose option not active, closing stdin and redirecting stdout and stderr
Redirecting stdout to /Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/logs/stdout.log
Redirecting stderr to /Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/logs/stderr.log
Press CTRL-C to shutdown the Quickstart server...
```

/Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/logs/stdout.log is showing this:

```
Loading quickstart properties: default
Loading quickstart properties: instance
Quickstart startup at Wed Jun 02 11:33:24 EDT 2021
UpgradeUtil.handleInstallAndUpgrade has mode RESTART
02.06.2021 11:33:24.188 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=/Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart (command line)
02.06.2021 11:33:24.189 *INFO * [main] Starting Apache Sling in /Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart
02.06.2021 11:33:24.191 *INFO * [main] Sling  Extension Lib Home : /Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/launchpad/ext
02.06.2021 11:33:24.195 *INFO * [main] Checking launcher JAR in folder /Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/launchpad
02.06.2021 11:33:24.205 *INFO * [main] Existing launcher is up to date, using it: 5.6.10.2_6_26 (org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar)
02.06.2021 11:33:24.206 *INFO * [main] Loading launcher class org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate from org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar
02.06.2021 11:33:24.206 *INFO * [main] External Libs Home (ext) is null or does not exists.
02.06.2021 11:33:24.213 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.properties=conf/sling.properties
02.06.2021 11:33:24.213 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=/Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart
02.06.2021 11:33:24.213 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.launchpad=/Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/launchpad
02.06.2021 11:33:24.213 *INFO * [main] Setting org.osgi.service.http.port=4502
02.06.2021 11:33:24.213 *INFO * [main] Starting launcher ...
02.06.2021 11:33:24.218 *INFO * [main] HTTP server port: 4502
02.06.2021 11:33:24.353 *INFO * [main] Startup completed
```

/Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/logs/stderr.log is showing:

```
Using 64bit VM settings, min.heap=1024MB, min permgen=256MB, default fork arguments=[-Xmx1024m, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m]
The JVM reports a heap size of 2048 MB, meets our expectation of 1024 MB +/- 20
Setting properties from filename '/Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar'
Verbose option not active, closing stdin and redirecting stdout and stderr
Redirecting stdout to /Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/logs/stdout.log
Redirecting stderr to /Users/jimmymona/Development/OnBeat/TFS/crx-quickstart/logs/stderr.log
ResourceProvider paths=[/gui, /gui/default]
```

So it looks like everything is running properly, but localhost:4502 is showing "This site can’t be reached" with "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".  I am not running any Proxies and my Firewall is off, not sure what else to check.  Any ideas?

Comment: try `netstat -nlp | grep :4502` to see that you have the port opened or not

Comment: `netstat: option requires an argument -- p`

Comment: did you type `netstat -nlp | grep :4502` completely?

Comment: Yes I did, it gives that response

Comment: @AmirRezaMohammadi I believe it requires protocol. I tried `netstat -nlp tcp | grep :4502` but there are not results

Comment: If I dont include the : I get some results  

  
`tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.175.59706    18.217.23.86.4502      ESTABLISHED`

`tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.175.59705    18.217.23.86.4502      ESTABLISHED`

Comment: @AmirRezaMohammadi How would I fix if the port was closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting crx-quickstart folder and restarting the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to figure out which process is blocking the 4502 port, but you can start AEM on a different port, rename your jar to cq-author-p4504.jar, cq-author-p8080.jar, or any other port. Of course, you will have to configure maven and any other tool or utility to deploy your code which assumes 4502 as the default port.

Comment: Tried renaming, but it the same error happens on whatever port I give it.  If the port is really blocked shouldn't it be throwing an error instead of saying "Startup completed"

Comment: Yeah, that is a little confusing, what is more, per documentation, AEM will try until it finds the next available port. What you can do is to find first the process id and then, using that id to find what port is using. See: "The default port for AEM is 4502. If that port is not available or already in use, Quickstart automatically configures itself to use the first available port number as follows: 4502, 8080, 8081, 8082, 8083, 8084, 8085, 8888, 9362, <random>."

Comment: Then, the startup completed maybe is because AEM indeed is running, but you do not know what port is using. You can delete the crx-quickstart and then try renaming again, since probably the random port is persisted in the AEM configuration and it will ignore the port in the file name.